# Determine for which aggregation a bean is created

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have the following definition:

```
<bean id="logger" factory-method="createLog" scope="prototype" class="com.test.beans.LogBean" ></bean>

<bean id="aone" class="com.test.beans.AggregationOne">
    <property name="log" ref="logger"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="atwo" class="com.test.beans.AggregationTwo">
    <property name="log" ref="logger"></property>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to recognize for which object (aone or atwo) bean 'logger' is being created?

Why I'm asking: in a legacy application I have one log instance for all classes. I want to change level for some packages, but can't do that (except using filters, what I don't want). For that purpose I want to utilize some spring magic, if it exists for that case )

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done this way. What you could try is a `BeanPostProcessor` implementation which detects common logger object in beans and replaces it with a specific one.